# haskell can not construct infinite type

Tags: haskell

I'm new to haskell.
I wrote a simple code.
But it does not work.
I'm getting this 'can not construct infinite type' error.
How does it fix.

```
reverse' list
        | null list = []
        | otherwise = (reverse' (tail list)) : (head list)
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem arises from your use of the `:` operator, which has the type

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

So it takes an element and a list, and returns a new list with that element prepended on.  Where you have

```
reverse' (tail list) : head list
-- parentheses removed since they're not needed
```

the type of `reverse' (tail list)` is `[a]`, and the type of `head list` is `a`, so the compiler tries to make it so that `a ~ [a]`, which obviously can't work.  Instead, you can use the `++` operator and put `head list` into a list itself:

```
reverse' (tail list) ++ [head list]
```

But keep in mind that this is not a very efficient solution, concatenation onto the end of Haskell lists is slow since they're singly linked lists.

Comment: @antoniomasa One of the most useful tricks for learning about a function or type is the `:info` (abbreviated `:i`) command in GHCi.  Try out things like `:i (:)`, `:i Int`, `:i Num`, and more to explore this interactive tool.  It'll help out a lot when trying to figure out how to use a function or data type.

Comment: concatenation onto the end is not _that_ slow thanks to laziness.

Comment: @Nicolas I decided to benchmark it using criterion ([code and report here](https://gist.github.com/bheklilr/3870492f79337c204156)) with essentially identical algorithms. The numbers speak for themselves, using lists, it took on average 1.15s for a 10000 element list with a stddev of 92.5ms.  Using `Data.Seq` on the same list (just converted to a sequence), the mean was 1.0ms with a stddev of 123.1us.  That's roughly a 1000x speed increase by using `Data.Seq`.  For fun I added a few other benchmarks that you can see in that gist, the fastest being `Prelude.reverse`. Laziness won't save you here

Comment: @Nicolas, it's not that slow if you have just one or a few concatenations (and you're actually traversing the list rather than just a deepSeq-for-fun) because laziness will fuse the loops for you. If you're doing a whole lot of concatenations, you'll start burning time in the inner loop. Furthermore, you may still have a problem (especially if you use the list in a heavily persistent fashion) because all the garbage conses will smash your cache.