# Trying to implement a simple recursive list traversing algorithm in Haskell. Dying

Tags: haskell

I'm trying hard to learn Haskell here </3, thought [Advent of Code](https://adventofcode.com/) would be a good place to test the language, but I'm dying here.

### The problem:

> Find the two entries that sum to 2020; what do you get if you multiply them together?

### My solution (in my head):

So I'm thinking I'm super smart here:

If I sort it first, I can just move inwards from the two endpoints until I find the two that sum to 2020:

i.e.

Given: `[1, 5000, 2, 4000, 3, 3000, 1009, 1010]`

I'll sort it `[1, 2, 3, 1009, 1010, 3000, 4000, 5000]`
Then check `1` against the end until it's less than `2020` (reaching `1010`)
Then check `1010` against the start until it's more than `2020` (reaching the goal of `1009`)

---

### How to read input and write output in Haskell:

I read [this tutorial](https://icpc.kattis.com/help/haskell) on input/output

and copied this code:

```
solve [] = []
solve (a:b:rest) = abs(a - b):(solve rest)

readInput = (map read) . words
writeOutput = unlines . (map show)

main = interact (writeOutput . solve . readInput)
```

which runs perfectly with the input

```
1 2
3 5
```

### My solution (in Haskell):

So first I'll just import `sort` and add it before `solve`

```
import Data.List (sort)

solve [] = []
solve (a:b:rest) = abs(a - b):(solve rest)

readInput = (map read) . words -- turn string into array of int
writeOutput = unlines . (map show) -- turn array of int into string

main = interact (writeOutput . solve . sort . readInput)
```

It works, but of course nothing changes. I also change the input to

```
1
5000
2
4000
3
3000
1009
1010
```

Still working (of course the output changes) so now I make THE BIG CHANGE

```
import Data.List (sort)

-- to be able to easily access the last element i simply reverse rest
-- turning [2, ..., 5000] into [5000, ..., 2]
solve (a:rest) = traverseFromEnd a:(reverse rest) 

traverseFromEnd (a:b:rest) -- i.e (1, 5000, [4000, ..., 2])
  | a + b > 2020 = traverseFromEnd a:rest -- if 1 + 5000 > 2020 we keep going and check 4000
  | a + b < 2020 = traverseFromStart b:(reverse rest) -- when we reach 1010, we start to check it against the start of the list
  | otherwise = [a * b] -- we've found a + b == 2020

traverseFromStart (a:b:rest)-- i.e (1010, 2, [3, ..., 1009])
  | a + b < 2020 = traverseFromStart a:rest -- if 1010 + 2 < 2020 we keep going and check 3
  | a + b > 2020 = traverseFromEnd b:(reverse rest) -- won't reach this in this example (not sure if reachable?
  | otherwise = [a * b] -- we've found a + b == 2020
```

But now I get this(!!?)

```
test.hs:13:36: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
    • In the first argument of ‘traverseFromEnd’, namely ‘a’
      In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘traverseFromEnd a’
      In the expression: traverseFromEnd a : rest
    • Relevant bindings include
        rest :: [a] (bound at test.hs:12:24)
        b :: a (bound at test.hs:12:22)
        a :: a (bound at test.hs:12:20)
        traverseFromStart :: [a] -> [a] (bound at test.hs:12:1)
   |
13 |   | a + b < 2020 = traverseFromEnd a:rest -- if 1010 + 2 < 2020 we keep going and check 3
   |
```

I mean I don't even know where to begin to understand this error message? :(((

Found similar issue in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23772866/haskell-can-not-construct-infinite-type) but can't see that I'm making the same mistake? I'm using : to append a (element) to rest (list) which should be correct?

Ok so maybe I need to wrap them in a parentheses so that the appending happen before we call traverseEnd again? So if I wrap all my calls in parentheses:

```
import Data.List (sort)

-- to be able to easily access the last element i simply reverse rest
-- turning [2, ..., 5000] into [5000, ..., 2]
solve (a:rest) = traverseFromEnd (a:(reverse rest))

traverseFromEnd (a:b:rest) -- i.e (1, 5000, [4000, ..., 2])
  | a + b > 2020 = traverseFromEnd (a:rest) -- if 1 + 5000 > 2020 we keep going and check 4000
  | a + b < 2020 = traverseFromStart (b:(reverse rest)) -- when we reach 1010, we start to check it against the start of the list
  | otherwise = [a * b] -- we've found abs(a + b) == 2020

traverseFromStart (a:b:rest)-- i.e (1010, 2, [3, ..., 1009])
  | a + b < 2020 = traverseFromStart (a:rest) -- if 1010 + 2 < 2020 we keep going and check 3
  | a + b > 2020 = traverseFromEnd (b:(reverse rest)) -- won't reach this in this example (not sure if reachable?
  | otherwise = [a * b] -- we've found abs(a + b) == 2020

readInput = (map read) . words -- turn string into array of int
writeOutput = unlines . (map show) -- turn array of int into string

main = interact (writeOutput . solve . sort . readInput)
```

But now I get:

```
test.hs: test.hs:(7,1)-(10,23): Non-exhaustive patterns in function traverseFromEnd
```

Ok... so I add some base-cases:

```
import Data.List (sort)

-- to be able to easily access the last element i simply reverse rest
-- turning [2, ..., 5000] into [5000, ..., 2]
solve (a:rest) = traverseFromEnd (a:(reverse rest))

traverseFromEnd [] = []
traverseFromEnd (a:[]) = [a]
traverseFromEnd (a:b:rest) -- i.e (1, 5000, [4000, ..., 2])
  | a + b > 2020 = traverseFromEnd (a:rest) -- if 1 + 5000 > 2020 we keep going and check 4000
  | a + b < 2020 = traverseFromStart (b:(reverse rest)) -- when we reach 1010, we start to check it against the start of the list
  | otherwise = [a * b] -- we've found abs(a + b) == 2020

traverseFromStart [] = []
traverseFromStart (a:[]) = [a]
traverseFromStart (a:b:rest)-- i.e (1010, 2, [3, ..., 1009])
  | a + b < 2020 = traverseFromStart (a:rest) -- if 1010 + 2 < 2020 we keep going and check 3
  | a + b > 2020 = traverseFromEnd (b:(reverse rest)) -- won't reach this in this example (not sure if reachable?
  | otherwise = [a * b] -- we've found abs(a + b) == 2020

readInput = (map read) . words -- turn string into array of int
writeOutput = unlines . (map show) -- turn array of int into string

main = interact (writeOutput . solve . sort . readInput)
```

But now it just spits out `1010`

So now it looks like we're just traversing through the list in `traverseFromEnd` and then reach the base case returning [a], which is so strange because it looks like we're never each the guard `| a + b < 2020 = traverseFromStart (b:(reverse rest))` (which we should when `a = 1`, `b = 1010` and `rest = [1009, 3, 2]`).

But I don't even know how to start debugging Haskell-code :S

This might be a hopeless endeavour after all. Unless someone knows what's going on in my code, writing the solution in python will feel so absurdly blissful by now

All the best!

Comment: 1009 + 1010 /= 2020. This input doesn't have a solution to the problem as stated here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to start debugging Haskell code is the same way you start debugging Python code: you hop in the REPL, and find the smallest input that doesn't give you the output you expected. For example, start with your list and start deleting elements:

```
> solve [1,2,3,1009,1010,3000,4000,5000] -- the starting point
[1010]
> solve [2,3,1009,1010,3000,4000,5000] -- delete the first element that we think isn't part of the solution
[1010]
```

If you keep iterating that step, eventually you will find

```
> solve [1009,1010]
[1010]
```

This can't be reduced any further without getting rid of what we think is the solution. To make further progress, let's dive into the definition of `solve`:

```
solve (a:rest) = traverseFromEnd (a:(reverse rest))
```

Okay, so `solve (1009:[1010])` becomes `traverseFromEnd (1009:[1010])`. Again we can't reduce this input any further, so dive into the definition of `traverseFromEnd`:

```
traverseFromEnd (a:b:rest) -- i.e (1, 5000, [4000, ..., 2])
  | a + b > 2020 = traverseFromEnd (a:rest) -- if 1 + 5000 > 2020 we keep going and check 4000
  | a + b < 2020 = traverseFromStart (b:(reverse rest)) -- when we reach 1010, we start to check it against the start of the list
  | otherwise = [a * b] -- we've found abs(a + b) == 2020
```

So `traverseFromEnd (1009:1010:[])` binds `a` to `1009` and `b` to `1010`. Let's check our guards in the repl. Before you do, choose in your mind which guard you *want* it to go to. I will assume you wanted it to choose the `otherwise` clause.

```
> 1009 + 1010 > 2020
False
```

This is fine, we didn't want it to pick this guard anyway.

```
> 1009 + 1010 < 2020
True
```

Uh-oh! It chose this guard instead of the one we wanted. We now have two choices: we can, after thinking a while, either decide that the guard is buggy or that our expectations are buggy. Which do you think is the case here?

In any case, this has narrowed down where the bug may be, and given us a place to stare, think, and modify -- which is the goal of having a debugging process in mind.

To summarize:

1. Reduce the input as far as possible.
2. Reduce definitions as far as possible.
3. Iterate (1) and (2) until you reach a piece of code+input that's small enough that you can understand why your expectations and the evaluated results don't match. Then fix one or the other of them.

Comment: I don't tend to debug code in GHCi. Better to set up a small test suite, then there's no need to manually try the individual tests over and over again. I recommend https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty

Comment: @leftaroundabout A test suite is great, but once it finds a mistake you still need some methodology for working out how to fix the mistake. And it goes vice versa, as well: as you find bugs, you can add to your test suite. I don't see "debugging in ghci" and "test suite" as opponents -- they complement each other.

Comment: Sure, sometimes dropping into the REPL is the easiest – but I persist: usually the best way to _find the mistake_ is to just make the test suite more fine-grained. It doesn't really take longer than writing the same stuff on the REPL (often it takes _less_ time because you already have the imports and QuickCheck in place), and then it doesn't take any additional time at all to add newly-found tests to the suite. To me, GHCi is mostly for one-off experiments outside of any project, that are probably never going to be needed again in the future.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Okay, sure. I'm not married to the REPL as the only way to run code. Whatever your favorite way to get some experiments going, I think the conclusion of this answer (steps 1, 2, and 3) apply, and describe which experiments are likely to be fruitful to get going. And this is the point I was trying to make (badly) in my previous comment: *just* saying "write tests" is not enough. You must know which tests to write. This answer is about how to know that. Perhaps for you, steps 1, 2, and 3 are so second-nature that you don't even think about them any more. But beginners need tips.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see where your code goes wrong, but I can suggest a few improvements to improve clarity (and speed).

First, you are using a single list argument where the content has a rather peculiar form: either it's `[maximum, rest in ascending order ...]` or `[minimum, rest in descending order ...]`. This makes the code a bit hard to read, and I would suggest to split the maximum/minimum into a separate argument.

Second, you should always start coding a function by writing the intended type. If you don't, and make a mistake, GHC will often infer a type which you did not expect. This will cause type errors much later on in the code, making them hard to fix, or produce error messages which are harder to understand.

Third, you are reversing the list too many times. Reversing is an O(n) operation, so we should try to avoid using it frequently. Fortunately, we can just reverse *once* in the whole program.

```
solve :: [Int] -> Int
solve xs = traversal zs (reverse zs)   -- the only reverse we will need!
   where zs = sort xs

traversal :: [Int]     -- ^ the input, in ascending order
          -> [Int]     -- ^ the same input, but in descending order
          -> Int
traversal []     _  = error "solution not found"
traversal _      [] = error "solution not found"
traversal (x:xs) (y:ys)
   | x > y        = error "solution not found"
   | x + y < 2020 = traversal xs     (y:ys)   -- drop the min x
   | x + y > 2020 = traversal (x:xs) ys       -- drop the max y
   | otherwise    = x*y                       -- found it
```

Here I was lazy and use `error` to make the program die when a solution is not found. A better approach would be to change the return type to `Maybe Int` so that we can return `Nothing` or `Just solution`, making our function total.

When the above solution drops a value, it only drops it from one of the two lists, since removing it from the other too would be expensive. Because of that, I added a test `x > y` to detect if we are traversing items which we have already discarded from the other list, so that we can stop the algorithm early.

Comment: Hey! Thanks! I got this error:


`test.hs:21:32: error: • Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘[a0]’ : Expected type: String -> [a0] : Actual type: String -> Int`

If I don't return x*y as a list? Looks like it's in the writeOutput-function that wants a list and the interpret -function wants a string

Comment: @MrJalapeno My `solve` returns a single `Int` instead of a list, so you can use `writeOutput = show` or `writeOutput = (++"\n") . show` if you need the new-line. Or you could modify the code above so that a list is returned instead.

Comment: Thank you, I love your solution btw, helped me understand Haskell a lot better :)